# Power series of Hermite polynomial generating function

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The generating function for Hermite polynomials is: $e^{-s^2+2s\xi} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}H_n(\xi) \frac{s^n}{n!}$. How does one do the power series expansion for $e^{-s^2+2s\xi}$?

Comment: Do you know how to expand $e^x$? Substitute $x\to-s^2+2s\xi$.

Comment: oh that’s easy. i thought had to treat $s$ like $x$ and did powers of $s$

Comment: *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics with Applications to Chemistry* by Linus Pauling-E.Bright Wilson, McGraw-Hill 1935 :  $\S$11c. Mathematical Properties of the Harmonic Oscillator Wave Functions.